# Filter two columns basing on another DataFrame and then fill remaining values from that another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

There are two DataFrames: df and source_df.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(9,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df.loc[4:7,'A']=123
    df.loc[5,'B']='name_1'
    df.loc[6,'B']='name_2'
    df.loc[1,'B']='name_1'

    source={'A':123,'B':'name_1', 'C':'value3', 'D':'value4'}
    source_df=pd.DataFrame(source, index=[0])
    print('df:\n', df,'\n')

    print('source_df:\n', source_df)

    df:
          A       B    C    D
    0  522     843  409  862
    1  522  name_1  861  793
    2  230     181  329  483
    3  542     152  531  960
    4  123     432  995  604
    5  123  name_1  641  158
    6  123  name_2  768  868
    7  123     874  455  620
    8    4     347  157  891 

    source_df:
          A       B       C       D
    0  123  name_1  value3  value4
```

My task is:

-to filter in df the rows whose values in columns A, B are in columns A, B of the source_df accordingly.

-within this selection to fill in columns C and D with according values from source_df

desired output is:

```
         A       B        C        D
    0  522     843      409      862
    1  522  name_1      861      793
    2  230     181      329      483
    3  542     152      531      960
    4  123     432      995      604
    5  123  name_1  value_3  value_4
    6  123  name_2      768      868
    7  123     874      455      620
    8    4     347      157      891
```

So far I tried to do the first part of my task:

```
    criteria1=df.A.isin([source_df.A])
    criteria2=df.B.isin([source_df.B])
    df[criteria1 & criteria2]
```

but for some reason, it doesn't generate any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), for correct match rows is used `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])
source_df1 = source_df.set_index(['A','B'])

df1.update(source_df1)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print(df1)
     A       B       C       D
0  266     826     639     583
1  765  name_1     771     142
2  282     387     473     841
3  687     747     425     762
4  123     663     188     114
5  123  name_1  value3  value4
6  123  name_2     515     669
7  123     431     748     162
8  312     669     834     248
```

Comment: Exactly what I was just going to post :( (except inplacing the set/reset index stuff)

Comment: @jezrael Why did you set and then reset index?

Comment: @SergeyBelousov - For align data - it means solution working for intersection of `A`, `B` columns values